# OneSignal. List of notifications?

Tags: list, notifications, push, onesignal

I am using a universal app template that uses OneSignal for push notifications which works perfect, however once the notification is dismissed or the app is opened it goes away and no way for the user to retrieve it or see if ever again.

I don’t know much programming and know just enough html to get me by. So I went through one signal documentation and found this.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#view-notifications

So I created the php file and it does pull the list. Awesome! However it pulls a ton of info the user does not need to see and is poorly formatted. Is there a way of altering this code so I can display only the date, title and message?